# Ubuntu 18.04 crashed, how to get bookmarks backup

Tags: crash, bookmarks

My Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OS crshed. I tried to import bookmark of firefox and cromoum from crashed ubuntu veersion via live USB trial. I performed following steps -

1. Went to Ubuntu installed volume /dev/sdb4
2. Then home/user(jeeva)/.mozilla/firefox/44djfg5e.default-release
3. Copied bookmarkbackup folder into live trial ubuntu home/.mozila/firebox/4r7zhham.default-release
4. Tried to backup bookmark but not succeeded.
5. Again I copied all firefox and cromium folder from crashed ubuntu 18.04 LTS home/jeeva/.confog folder to my other drive.

Please help me how I get backup from all these bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your old installation (i.e. file system is readable), you may be able to use profile import on your new system.

To do so, follow the following documentation:
For Chrome: `[How to Backup and Restore Google Chrome Profile On Linux][1]`
For Firefox: [Recovering important data from an old profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile#w_bookmarks-downloads-and-browsing-history)
(you can also use the information found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox), just as a reference).

However, as you are using a live version of Ubuntu, you may need to create persistent storage first, for these options to work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer, I'd suggest you to copy whole /home/jeeva directory to eg. USB or other external storage, then it should be easy to restore it all after reinstall.

Firefox stores to:
'/home//. mozilla/firefox/'
and Chrome to:
'/home//. config/google-chrome/default'

Literally if you just copy files to correct folders you should have everything, not just bookmarks.